# Math Brain Teaser! Can't solve, please help!

Tags: puzzle

> The sum of face values of two coins is twice the difference of the two. Find them.

My math professor gave us a brain teaser, but I am extremely confused on how to solve it. I am aware that it might be a April Fool's joke, but he still wants a solution.. I know that one coin must be three times the other.

Comment: If they were banknotes, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Dollar_Bill

Comment: There must be several (circulating and historical) world currencies which have one denomination of coin which is three times the other: the Bahamas, for one.  This really is off-topic for math, it takes nothing more than Wikipedia footwork.

Answer (score 6):

A ratio of three is a rarity in coinage systems.  They tend to use $1,2,5$ and things like that.  I thought to check the old [British coinage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_coinage), because I knew it had funny values.  Sure enough

> In the years just prior to decimalisation, the circulating British
>   coins were the half crown (2/6), two shillings or florin (2/-),
>   shilling (1/-), sixpence (6d), threepence (3d), penny (1d) and
>   halfpenny (½d).

So my answer would be a threepence and a penny.

Comment: That makes sense! thank you so much. It kinda also explains the pirate theme.

Comment: There may be other systems that have a ratio of three as well.  I didn't try to find them.  With the pirate theme, you might also think of six and two out of [pieces of eight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pieces_of_eight) which in childhood I was told could be broken into eight pieces.  But it seems not to be so.